# Linq two DataTables together results in "Enumeration yielded no results"

Tags: c#, linq

Running this code

```
var joinedTables = from comment in dtComments.AsEnumerable()
                                       join summaryTable in summaryData.AsEnumerable() on comment.Field<string>("RESOURCE") equals summaryTable.Field<string>("CELL_NAME") into ps
                                       from r in ps.AsEnumerable()
                                       select r;
```

Returns "Enumeration yielded no results" when debugging the code.

I essentially want it to do the equivalent of this SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM summaryTable
JOIN dtComments ON summaryTable.CELL_NAME = dtComments.RESOURCE
```

I checked the data of both DataTables, and they should be able to match many rows.

I tried debugging using the following lines of code, just to make sure I can get simple results, and they did work.

```
var test = from x in dtComments.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("RESOURCE") == "HP08") select x;

var test2 = from y in summaryData.AsEnumerable() select y;
```

Comment: How about `var test2 = from x in summaryData.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("CELL_NAME") == "HP08") select x;`. Does it also return records like `test`?

Comment: @Ivan, ah nice test.  It doesn't return a result.  How do I apply a trim() to the CELL_NAME column?

Comment: Nevermind, got the trim, I'm going to give it a test.

Comment: So, I'm getting results in the joinedTables var now.  But, it doesn't include all of the columns from the dtComments table.  Why is that?

Comment: Because you are selecting only the records from the `summaryData` (`select r`)

Comment: When I put the "into ps".  Is it not putting the matching data from both tables into ps?

Comment: No, only the inner (right) record. Basically `r` is the same as `summaryTable` variable, but matching the `comment`. You can remove the `into ps from r in ps.AsEnumerable()` part and use something like `select new { comment, summaryTable }`